# JMSSecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid for ActiveMQ Classic from Docker image

Tags: docker, curl, jms, activemq-classic

I've set up an ActiveMQ Classic broker via Docker:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre

RUN curl -O http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/5.18.2/apache-activemq-5.18.2-bin.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /opt/apache/activemq
RUN tar xvzf apache-activemq-5.18.2-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/apache/activemq

WORKDIR /opt/apache/activemq/apache-activemq-5.18.2/bin
VOLUME /opt/apache/activemq/apache-activemq-5.18.2/conf

RUN echo './activemq start && tail -f /opt/apache/activemq/apache-activemq-5.18.2/data/activemq.log' > start.sh

# Admin interface
EXPOSE 8161
# Active MQ's default port (Listen port)
EXPOSE 61616

CMD ["/bin/bash", "./start.sh"]
```

When sending a JMS message to the broker via `curl`, e.g.:

```
curl.exe -XPOST -d "@SomeJsonFile.json" http://admin:admin@localhost:8161/api/message?destination=queue://SOME.LOCAL.NONEXISTENT.QUEUE
```

I get an error:

```
activemq-test-container-1  | javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not post JMS message: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid.
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
activemq-test-container-1  | Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not post JMS message: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid.
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
activemq-test-container-1  |    ... 12 more
activemq-test-container-1  | Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not post JMS message: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid.
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet.doPost(MessageServlet.java:151)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:554)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
activemq-test-container-1  |    ... 14 more
activemq-test-container-1  | Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid.
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:65)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1465)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1548)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:568)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.getConnection(WebClient.java:262)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.createSession(WebClient.java:359)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.web.WebClient.getSession(WebClient.java:250)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServletSupport.getDestination(MessageServletSupport.java:335)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServletSupport.getDestination(MessageServletSupport.java:283)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet.doPost(MessageServlet.java:127)
activemq-test-container-1  |    ... 32 more
activemq-test-container-1  | Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid.
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.security.SimpleAuthenticationBroker.authenticate(SimpleAuthenticationBroker.java:103)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.security.SimpleAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(SimpleAuthenticationBroker.java:71)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:850)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:333)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:198)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onCommand(ResponseCorrelator.java:116)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.iterate(VMTransport.java:275)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
activemq-test-container-1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
activemq-test-container-1  |    ... 1 more
activemq-test-container-1  | 2024-01-09 13:47:50,541 | INFO  | Stopping vm://localhost#0 because Failed with SecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-3
```

I'm unsure where the "system" user comes from, as I haven't configured security yet. I'm also getting the same error when I try to send a message via admin console on `http://localhost:8161/admin/send.jsp`, or when I try to access an existing queue under `http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp`.

Maybe I've understood something wrong, but it seems there's a 2-layer authentication here? `admin:admin` to access the admin console / the API, and a separate authentication for accessing queues? How would I be able to set JMS username / password via `curl`?